# add item to MPMediaItemCollection from NSURL

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmediaitemcollection

In .plist file I keep NSURLs of audio files from iPod library. I need to initialize MPMediaItemCollection items by these urls.

How can I do that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
keep it here, if someone will need same thing once

```
MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

    NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items];

    for (MPMediaItem *song in itemsFromGenericQuery) 
    {            
        if ([savedUrl isEqual:[song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]])
        {
            ownMediaItemCollection = [MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems: [NSArray arrayWithObject:song]];
        }
    }
    [everything release];
```